# Declaring a Variable and using it as a Parameter

Tags: variables, plsql, parameters

I am trying to write some code which will declare a variable and then use it as a parameter. I use this in SQL all the time, but don't seem to be able to figure out how to do it in PL/SQL and have not found any info that has helped me figure it out.

Here is an example of what I have tried.

```
DECLARE
  DEPT VARCHAR2(50) := 'HDS - ITS Storage Services';

BEGIN
   SELECT 
      SUBMIT_DATE,
      CLOSE_DATE, 
   FROM 
      sm_admin.ocmlm1
   WHERE 
      ASSIGNED_DEPT = DEPT
END;
 /
```

Answer (score 0):

Declaration of DEPT variable is fine, however you are missing INTO clause in the query. If you execute SELECT inside PL/SQL block, you must specify to what variable the result is fetched.

Note that the below code will work only if the query returns exactly one row.

```
DECLARE
  DEPT VARCHAR2(50) := 'HDS - ITS Storage Services';
  V_S_DATE  sm_admin.ocmlm1.submit_date%TYPE;
  V_C_DATE  sm_admin.ocmlm1.close_date%TYPE;

BEGIN
   SELECT 
      SUBMIT_DATE,
      CLOSE_DATE
   INTO v_S_DATE, V_C_DATE 
   FROM 
      sm_admin.ocmlm1
   WHERE 
      ASSIGNED_DEPT = DEPT;
END;
```